# Android pairing request settings

Tags: android, bluetooth

I use the createBondMethod() from API19 to pair a Blutooth LE device. The log of a bluetooth sniffers shows the Pairing Request from the Tablet to the Bluetooth device.

The following pairing request setting were used:

Bluetooth Security Manager Protocol

- AuthReqBonding

  - Bonding Flag = 1
  - MITM Flag = 1
- InitiatorKey

  - Encryption Key = 1
  - Id Key = 1
  - Signature Key = 1
- Responder Key

  - Encryption Key = 1
  - Id Key = 1
  - Signature Key = 1

How can i change the MITM-Flag and the Initiator/ResponderKey settings through the android api (Level19)?